# python pandas ... alternatives to iterrows in pandas to get next rows value (NEW)

Tags: python, pandas, iterator

I have a df in pandas

import pandas as pd

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['AA', 'BB', 'CC'], columns = ['value'])`

I want to iterate over rows in df. For each row i want rows value and next rows value.

Here is the desired result.

`0 1 AA BB
1 2 BB CC`

I have tried a pairwise() function with itertools.

`from itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['AA', 'BB', 'CC'], columns = ['value'])

for (i1, row1), (i2, row2) in pairwise(df.iterrows()):
    print i1, i2, row1["value"], row2["value"]`

But, its too slow. Any idea how to achieve the output with iterrows ? I would like to try pd.apply for a large dataset.

Comment: Why do you want the rows in pairs?  I believe this question is the symptom of a larger issue.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Anyway to use pd.apply function ?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html), then use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to throw out the last row:

```
df['next_value'] = df.value.shift(-1)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
>>> df
        value   next_value
0          AA           BB
1          BB           CC
```

Comment: with `df.set_index(df.index+1,append=True,inplace=True)` to complete the index.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not the most "fancy" way - I would just use a numeric iterator and access lines i and i+1